# Trying to use HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: dll, html-agility-pack

Im having problems trying to install the HtmlAgilityPack.dll ver 1.4. I've copied the files into my windows\system32 folder and tried regsvr32 htmlagilitypack.dll in run.

I got the following error:

```
The module was loaded but the entry point DllUnregisterServer was not found.
```

It seems to be a common library used by many people on SO so the dll's cant be corrupted. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't use `regsvr32` is because the HTML Agility pack isn't a COM library. It's written in .NET, so you need to reference from a .NET project.

1. Download the latest zip file and extract somewhere on your local hard disk e.g. `c:\SharedLibs\HtmlAgilityPack`.
2. Launch Visual Studio (or one of the VS Express editions)
3. Create a new project or open an existing one.
4. In solution explorer right click on *References* and click *Add Reference*.
5. Click the *Browse* tab and browse to where you extracted the agility pack
6. Select the *HtmlAgilityPack.dll* DLL
7. Click OK

Refer to the CodePlex site:

> [Html Agility Pack Home](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
>   [Html Agility Pack Examples](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

Here's a couple of links I dug up in everyone's favourite search engine:

> [A simple web crawler in C# using HtmlAgilityPack](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/)
>   [.NET Html Agility Pack: How to use malformed HTML just like it was well-formed XML...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smourier/archive/2003/06/04/8265.aspx)

Comment: So where do I have to extract it to and what steps do I have to do to get it to work? Thank you.

Comment: @Nai, just as you reference any other assembly... where the file is doesn't really matter as long as the build process knows the path (which is the case if you add it with the Add Reference, Browse functionality in Visual Studio).